Can I check for an aircon leak by just pressurizing with air?
We have a MK5 VW GOLF from 2005 and we haven't had aircon for a few years (when be bought it the aircon didn't work and we haven't had it fixed/recharged since). I know it is a fairly easy job to recharge this myself but before doing so I wanted to check the system could actually hold pressure given it has been a while.
Am I able to just pressurize the system with an air compressor to see if it holds pressure or should I do something else? Also if it has been so long without working is there anything else I should check for?

The way to test for leaks is to vacuum the system out using a pump. There's two purposes for this, the first being checking for leaks. The second is, you need to do it before recharging the system in the first place to ensure there's no air in the system. Mind you, if it doesn't have pressure right now, it had to leak out somewhere. Vacuuming the system might help you find it. If there was/is a leak, you'd want to replace the dryer canister at the same time, as it will become contaminated over time due to air/moisture.

It's never recommended to pressurize any ac system with air as this adds moisture that's absorbed into the receiver/drier/accumulator canister next to the condenser coil. Once saturated, it's replaced, especially when a compressor, condenser coil or evaporator coil are replaced. The desiccant absorbs minute moisture in a sealed system circulating refrigerant, oil and dye. Every ac system is evacuated with all air and moisture removed, checked for leaks then filled with refrigerant at factory installation. In your case, a leak occurred somewhere, even from one or both service valves. Nitrogen is used on central hvac systems in commercial ac repairs. If you don't have access to nitrogen and dye was installed at factory assembly (greenish yellow oil in service valves), you can inject half a can of r134a into the system and start looking for leaks. An inexpensive uv blacklight can help find dye leaking out with refrigerant and oil. If dye wasn't installed, a can of r134a with dye can be injected. One 12oz can is sufficient to run ac. Be careful of cans containing dye, as some will be released during connections and disconnections. A rag covering fittings when connecting/disconnecting hoses will minimize dye spraying everywhere. Do not use sealer. If you get this far and find the source of the leak(s), you'll know what repairs are necessary and must use new O-rings on disconnected fittings. It might be wise to replace both valve stems at this point and use new caps after (hopefully) repairing this system. You'll need ac gauges and electric vacuum pump after repairs, to remove all air, refrigerant and moisture by running the vacuum pump for at least 30 minutes. Autozone is one place for free tool loan outs. Vacuum time allows moisture to 'boil out of oil and desiccant if you don't replace the drier. Once evacuated, gauge valves closed, observe both gauges, especially the low side as the needle displaying a near complete vacuum may or may not move towards zero(0), indicating a leak exists; seals, hoses, coupler fittings,  compressor front seal (from lack of lube), etc. Your goal is to see zero needle movement. Zero leak back of atmospheric/ambient air pressure back into a system after 15 minutes means you've successfully repaired this system and can refill with the appropriate amount of refrigerant (no sealer). The first can (12ozs) can be added without the engine running (the compressor will not turn on until the ac pressure sensor detects 40+psi of pressure. A can will display approximately 75 psi in warm weather. One can injected into the system, immersed in a bucket of warm water, is sufficient to start the engine and turn on ac. Leave the high side gauge valve closed as the manifold is a three way configuration with valves controlling which way vacuum and refrigerant flows. Never inject refrigerant into the high side as pressures will build up, exceeding 125 psi. Most cans of refrigerant have a bottom designed to vent excessive pressures from anyone unfamiliar with ac operating pressures. Be aware of high pressure explosion hazards when working on vehicle ac systems. One can may begin to cool with the second can injecting a few ounces at a time, with blower on medium speed, until cold air comes out the center vents. Refill to capacity. Don't overfill.

Yes, you can.
While drawing a vacuum on the system can tell the existence of leaks, it's hard to find the leaks with a vacuum, e.g. with soapy water. Additionally, a vacuum can have a 1 atm pressure difference max, lower than the operating pressures of ordinary vehicle AC systems, often 13-14 atm on the high side. Leaks that occur under pressure may seal themselves.
However, when you're pressurizing the system, you should use nitrogen if possible. This avoids introducing moisture to the system. You can often rent nitrogen equipment from welding supply stores.
In any case, you must use a regulator and pressure gauges and ensure the system does not exceed the safe levels recommended by the manufacturer.
